# Android debugging exceptions

Tags: android, exception

I have been working with Eclipse/Android development porting a game from windows for about a month now.
But I have been frustrated with some aspects of this Environment.
When I get an exception, very rarely does the debugger stop where it needs to.
I have tried adding Exception breakpoints, this helps hit a few errors in relevant code but still very hit and miss. 
Visual studio always stops execution in the closest entry point to the throwing of the exception, and I really miss that.
Even a minor

```
myArrayList[outOfBounds]
```

does not stop on the line that caused the issue.

**I would like to know what experienced android developers do to track down the cause of exceptions quickly.**

Answer (score 0):

Put a try{ block around the statements that are going to generate the exception and then in the catch do something like

```
catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Test \"" + arg +
                    "\" threw a " + e.getClass() +
                    "\n        with message: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I get this far, but the issue is, the only exception info, the stack i get is in source code belonging to the android framework. Not my source. The code i have is very computationally intensive, so placing try...catch block around everything really slows it down. I would just like the debugger to stop at the nearest code in my project. If I go down the call stack, there is no sign of the actual code causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use try - catch block. Whenever any exception comes your catch block will be executed so you can put alert or message in catch block to track your problem or you can use Exception parent class to trace your bug.

```
try{
       Your code to execute
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will give you error log in your logcat.

Comment: Thanks for your help, see above comment.

Comment: Sorry that would be below now ;)